# AWS lambda getting 'unauthorized to perfrom action' when using MongoClient, works fine with mongoose, works fine when running command from shell

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongoose

Here is the architecture:
I have a MongoDB running on an EC2. When I ssh to the EC2 and run `mongo dbname -u username -p password` I am able to perform insert into the collection so that should mean that the user has permission in dbname to perform insert on collection

On the other side I have an AWS lambda, VPC is configured. When using mongodb.MongoClient to connect I am authenticated and client.isConnected() returns true but db.collection().insertOne(...) raises an error saying that I'm not authorized to perform action insert on dbname.
The connection string used to connect contains the same username and password used to connect to mongo shell.
I tried using the same options for connection to mongodb, but used mongoose instead and it didn't raise any errors

Answer (score 0):

what is the connection string used?
can you try to simulate what the lambda is doing locally? can you try connecting with local mongo client to your db using the same connection string that your lambda use?

are you connecting to the right db? is your user setup on your custom db or on the default admin db? are your update rights setup on the right db?

Comment: The format is mongodb://username:password@host:27017/dbname
I cannot run the lambda using the same connection string because of VPC.
Yes I am connecting to the right DB because when I SSH to the EC2 and look at mongo logs I can see that I'm being connected and the logs say `Successfully authenticated as principal username on dbname from client ...`
but the next line says  `Unauthorized: not authorized on dbname to execute command insert`
The user is setup on the custom db and the permissions are setup because I'm able to run those commands in shell as the user username

Comment: And I'm having the same issue using the pymongo MongoClient when trying to do the same.
With mongoose in nodeJS I used the following
`const options = {

    tls: true,
    tlsinsecure: true,
    checkServerIdentity: false,
    auth: {
        user: String(process.env.MONGO_USERNAME),
        password: String(process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD),
        authSource: String(process.env.MONGO_SOURCE)
    }

};

mongoose.connect(MONGO_URL, options)`
And with this I was able do do insert